# Trying to find a panel discussion on the history of TSR that was posted to a gaming podcast

Tags: history-of-gaming, podcast, tsr

I listened to a podcast that had a panel with ~3 people from the heyday of TSR telling stories of their time there. I'd really like to find this interview again, but I listen to a lot of RPG podcasts, and I was exploring new ones when I listened to it, so I don't even know if I currently subscribe to the one it was from. I was hoping someone could help me out?

It was obviously from a panel recorded at a panel done at a con, as at the end after the official panel you could hear a few questions being answered as people were leaving.  One of the people was from the Dungeon/Dragon magazine editorial department, I forget where the other two were from. The stories included things such as TSRs content lack of chairs, TSRs habit of renting storage facilities then forgetting about them, the first big round of layoffs and what happened to the dioramas that adorned the TSR booth each year.

Does anyone have any idea what podcast this was, or anything else that could help me find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone contacted me about this elsewhere; It is the [PaizoCon 2013 Special 13: Secrets of TSR episode of the Know Direction subpodcast of 3.5 Private Sanctuary.](http://35privatesanctuary.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=541%3apaizocon2013-special-013-secrets-of-tsr&catid=35%3athe-tome-know-direction&Itemid=34)